# Загадка области видимости на JS

Tags: javascript

Структура данного проекта такая **(псевдокод)**

```
<.parent_1 style=pos-abs; z10>
  <.child_1>
  <.child_1>
  <.child_1>
</.parent_1>

<script>
   code..
<script>

<.parent_2 style=pos-abs; z5>
  <.child_2>
  <.child_2>
  <.child_2>
</.parent_2>
```

В скрипте **(который находится между блоками)** я по клику успешно запускаю функцию с параметром **MouseEvent** и без пробем могу получить доступ к `parent_2` хоть в верстке скрипт прописан **после** этого блока.

```
function click(MouseEvent) {
   
  let children = document.querySelectorAll('.child_1');
  // работает просто отлично
}
```

Но создав функцию **без** Этого эвента - до parent_2 и его детей не достучаться.

Вопрос, Существует ли метод написания функции с глобальной областью видимости, так что бы не переносить script под нижний блок?

Comment: Оберните весь код в функцию, в body пропишите `<body onload='вашаФункция'>` и будет вам счастье

Comment: Звучит очень интересно! Буду пробовать!

Comment: В данном случае проблемы не с областью видимости, а с тем, что код успевает отработать быстрее, чем браузер успел отрисовать элемент в DOM. Рекомендуется всегда запускать скрипты после полной отрисовки DOM дерева. Как раз событие onload вызывается тогда, когда документ готов

Comment: Можно вызвать не на body а на том блоке, что мне нужен?

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что ваш код вешает листнеры на элементы страницы

Comment: Это веб приложение, там не только Листенеры! Просто мне нужно что бы эта функция была доступно только в этом приложении, а запускаая на Бади, получится, что буду требовать запускать ее везде, хотя проект многостраницный PHP и открывающийся и закрывающийся тег Бади прописан единожды в одном инклюде

Comment: Ставьте атрибут `defer` в скрипт и не парьтесь) `<script defer>...</scirpt>`

Comment: @ΝNL993, это сработает если скрипт не Inline

Comment: @Grundy разве не наоборот?

Comment: @ΝNL993, обычно inline (стили или скрипты) - это то, что непосредственно в документе описано. В отличие от внешних, которые загружаются по указанному `src` :) под вопросом, я уже увидел, что почему-то у вас наоборот :) то есть: inline - `<script>console.log(1)</script>`, внешний скрипт - `<script src="path/to/script"></script>`

Comment: @Grundy видимо неправильно документацию прочитал :p

Answer (score 0):

## Почему не работает?

HTML читается сверху вниз. Интерпретатор доходит до скрипта, читает про `<.parent_2>`, а элемента то не существует - до него пока не дошли.

## Как решить?

Самый удобный для мой взгляд - это аттрибут `defer`...

```html
<.parent_1 style=pos-abs; z10>
  <.child_1>
  <.child_1>
  <.child_1>
</.parent_1>

<script src="ссылка на скрипт" defer></script>

<.parent_2 style=pos-abs; z5>
  <.child_2>
  <.child_2>
  <.child_2>
</.parent_2>
```

...которая не запускает скрипты, пока все дерево DOM не сгенерирован. Либо если очень хотите без ссылок, прям в html, напишите так:

```html
<.parent_1 style=pos-abs; z10>
  <.child_1>
  <.child_1>
  <.child_1>
</.parent_1>

<script>
  document.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`, () => {
    // code...
  })
</script>

<.parent_2 style=pos-abs; z5>
  <.child_2>
  <.child_2>
  <.child_2>
</.parent_2>
```

Собственно аттрибут `defer` делает тоже самое только в теневой DOM.

Comment: А на мой взгляд `defer`, такой себе атрибут, он работает только для инлайн скриптов, что как по мне очень неудобно, плюс к тому ещё и `defer` не работает с атрибутом `module`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 для не инлайн скриптов написал вариант. А про `module` не знаю. Я если и работаю с JS то только чистый DOM. Не использую этот аттрибут. :-)

Comment: Не заметил ответа с DOMCL :p, в любом случае получается что без defer лучше исключая инлайны конечно.

Comment: Господа, на данный момент меня устроил вариант который предложил @SwaD в комментах под моим вопросом, ```defer``` никогда не использовал, может потому что очень часто натыкаясь на его обсуждение попадал к результату, что это косяковый метод! Поэтому склонюсь больше к варианту с ```DOMContentLoaded``` в Листенере)